# Data from forms with enctype="multipart/form-data" not reaching controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have made an application using codeigniter, and everything was working fine few day ago. But suddenly, yesterday, when I ran the application, I am getting error, when I am submitting data from the forms which contain enctype="multipart/form-data". Null data is received at the controller. When I remove enctype, than everything goes fine, but due to image upload, I have to keep enctype in some form tags.

```
                <form action="<?= site_url('nasty_v2/dashboard/uploadPaid?key=').$this->my_func->scpro_encrypt("betul"); ?>" method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="portlet box purple-sharp">
                        <div class="portlet-title">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <i class="fa fa-image"></i>Upload Payment Proof For 
                            </div>                
                        </div>
                        <div class="portlet-body flip-scroll" align="center">
                        <span style = "color : #b706d6;"><h2><strong>#<?= (120000+$orid); ?></strong></h2></span>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" align="center" data-provides="fileinput">
                                <div class="fileinput-preview thumbnail" data-trigger="fileinput" style="width: 200px; height: 150px; line-height: 150px;"></div>
                                <div>
                                    <span class="btn red btn-outline btn-file">
                                        <span class="fileinput-new"> Select image </span>
                                        <span class="fileinput-exists"> Change </span>
                                        <input type="hidden" value="" name="title"><input type="file" name="fileImg"> </span>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn red fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> Remove </a>
                                </div><div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-upload"> Submit</i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="or_id" id="inputOr_id" class="form-control" value="<?= $or_id; ?>">                          
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I checked the HTTP request using Telerik Fiddler 2, and the found that form is successfully submitting data in request, but that data is not reaching controller.  What should be the issue?

Comment: Kindly share the controller code which you are using to access the Posted Data.

Comment: Here's the code from my Controller https://www.codepile.net/pile/zVvm3aJK

Comment: What I meant by my last comment was the code you are using to get image from post on server-side, which I assume is hidden in `$this->my_func->do_upload('./assets/uploads/img/');` as I can not see any code related to file upload. Please take a look at https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html